Can´t rx samples from multiple IPs with x310 and two twinRX using UHD Python API with multiprocessing
I am interested in acquiring multiple channels with my rig using the Python API. This is my setup: An x310 with two TwinRX , connections are 10 GB Ethernet for each TwinRX with a dedicated network card for each one (IPs are 192.168.30.2 and 192.168.40.2). I have UHD v4.6.0.0.0 installed and Ubuntu 22.04 with Python 3.10.12.
I use this code to receive samples from a single TwinRX and it works fine:
import argparse
import numpy as np
import uhd
import gc
import subprocess

def parse_args():
    """Parse the command line arguments"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--args", default="", type=str,
                        help="Additional arguments for the USRP device")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output-file", type=str, required=True,
                        help="Output file prefix where samples will be saved")
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--freq", type=float, required=True,
                        help="Center frequency in Hz")
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--rate", default=1e6, type=float,
                        help="Sample rate in Hz (default: 1e6)")
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--duration", default=5.0, type=float,
                        help="Duration of reception in seconds (default: 5.0)")
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--channels", default=[0, 1], nargs="+", type=int,
                        help="List of channel IDs to receive from (default: 0 1)")
    parser.add_argument("-g", "--gain", type=int, default=10,
                        help="Gain in dB (default: 10)")
    parser.add_argument("-n", "--numpy", default=False, action="store_true",
                        help="Save output file in NumPy format (default: No)")
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--ip-address", type=str, required=True,
                        help="IP address of the USRP device")
    return parser.parse_args()


def get_board_number(ip_address):
    """Extract board number from IP address"""
    parts = ip_address.split('.')
    return parts[-2]  # Extract the second-to-last part of the IP address


def main():
    """RX samples and write to file"""
    args = parse_args()
    usrp = uhd.usrp.MultiUSRP(f"addr={args.ip_address} {args.args}")
    usrp.set_rx_bandwidth(args.rate, 0)
    num_samps = int(np.ceil(args.duration * args.rate))
    board_number = get_board_number(args.ip_address)

    # Receive samples for both channels simultaneously
    samps = usrp.recv_num_samps(num_samps, args.freq, args.rate, args.channels, args.gain)

    print(f"Bandwidth: {usrp.get_rx_bandwidth(0)/1e6:.0f} MHz")
    print(f"Format of samples: {type(samps[0, 1])}")
    print(f"Shape of samples: {samps.shape}")
    print(f"Number of channels: {samps.shape[0]}")
    print(f"Number of samples per channel: {samps.shape[1]}")
    print(f"Size per .iq file: {samps.dtype.itemsize * num_samps / 1e6:.0f} MB")

    for channel_id, samples in zip(args.channels, samps):
        output_filename = f"{args.output_file}_{board_number}_{channel_id}.iq"
        print(f"Saving samples for TwinRX 192.168.{board_number}.2, channel {channel_id} to {output_filename}")
        samples.tofile(output_filename)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

But now I want to acquire samples from both twinRX simultaneously. Apparently threading doesn't work due to GIL limitations, but when I try to do multiprocessing with the following code I get errors:
import numpy as np
import uhd
import gc
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

# Hardcoded parameters
output_file = "muestras_prueba"
freq = 218.64e6
rate = 25e6
gain = 50
duration = 10
channels = [0, 1]
ips = ["192.168.30.2", "192.168.40.2"]

def get_board_number(ip_address):
    """Extract board number from IP address"""
    parts = ip_address.split('.')
    return parts[-2]  # Extract the second-to-last part of the IP address

def acquire_and_save_samples(ip_address, output_file, freq, rate, gain, duration, channels):
    """Acquire samples from USRP and save to file"""
    try:
        usrp = uhd.usrp.MultiUSRP(f"addr={ip_address}")
        usrp.set_rx_bandwidth(rate, 0)
        num_samps = int(np.ceil(duration * rate))
        board_number = get_board_number(ip_address)

        # Receive samples for both channels simultaneously
        samps = usrp.recv_num_samps(num_samps, freq, rate, channels, gain)

        print(f"Bandwidth: {usrp.get_rx_bandwidth(0)/1e6:.0f} MHz")
        print(f"Format of samples: {type(samps[0, 1])}")
        print(f"Shape of samples: {samps.shape}")
        print(f"Number of channels: {samps.shape[0]}")
        print(f"Number of samples per channel: {samps.shape[1]}")
        print(f"Size per .iq file: {samps.dtype.itemsize * num_samps / 1e6:.0f} MB")

        for channel_id, samples in zip(channels, samps):
            output_filename = f"{output_file}_{board_number}_{channel_id}.iq"
            print(f"Saving samples for TwinRX 192.168.{board_number}.2, channel {channel_id} to {output_filename}")
            samples.tofile(output_filename)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred with IP {ip_address}: {e}")

def main():
    """Main function to handle multiprocessing for sample acquisition"""
    processes = []
    for ip in ips:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=acquire_and_save_samples, args=(ip, output_file, freq, rate, gain, duration, channels))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    finally:
        command = "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
        subprocess.run(['sudo', 'sh', '-c', command])
        print("Caché freed successfully.")
        gc.collect()
        print("RAM freed successfully")


[WARNING] [RFNOC] chdr_ctrl_endpoint: Received async message for unknown destination. Source EPID: 2 Destination port: 7
[ERROR] [RFNOC::GRAPH] Error during initialization of block 0/Radio#1!
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
[ERROR] [RFNOC::GRAPH] An exception has been detected while initializing the graph: RfnocError: OpTimeout: Control operation timed out waiting for ACK
Error occurred with IP 192.168.30.2: RuntimeError: Failed to create rfnoc_graph.


What is the second piece of code supposed to achieve that the first does not?
